# What is the nonInheritingStyles property on the UIComponent for?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml, styles

What is the nonInheritingStyles property for on the UIComponent?

Is this a list of styles that the component does not inherit from the container?

Or is this a list of styles that have been set inline or in code so the component is just telling me that they are NOT inheriting from the container?

If it's the first why are their values set for this properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is this a list of styles that the component does not inherit from the container?"

YES